Email content changes on browser view
Tool Used: Salesforce Marketing Cloud
Process:
When a user places an order on the website,
they receive an order confirmation email.
This email is created using AMPscript in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
However, when the user opens the email in their browser by clicking the "read in browser" button, the content displayed is not the updated version, but rather the old content.
Note: The email has been published with the updated changes in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Check if you have a specific logic for pulling the data and/or content within _MessageContext == "VAWP"

Hey, I checked the logic and found no reference to _MessageContext == "VAWP". Could this be due to the email template we used?

You need to use the personalization string %%view_email_url%% to display the updated version of the email in the web.
